# compiling a proof of concept exploit

Tags: security

I am starting to test proof of concept exploits in my VM. I came across this Microsoft animated cursor vuln - MS07-017. 
I saw the process in exploit-db. The compilation is ok:-

```
Win32/VC++  : cl -o HOD-ms05002-ani-expl HOD-ms05002-ani-expl.c
Win32/cygwin: gcc -o HOD-ms05002-ani-expl HOD-ms05002-ani-expl.c
Linux       : gcc -o HOD-ms05002-ani-expl HOD-ms05002-ani-expl.c
```

But the next step is not understood:

```
C:\>HOD-ms05002-ani-expl.exe poc 7777
```

I see the same "poc(may be proof of concept)" in the command for linux too

```
$ HOD-ms05002-ani-expl poc 7777 192.168.0.30
```

What is the meaning of the above two commands?
I exploited the vulnerability in my XP virtual machine from Kali- metasploit and that was by XP visiting the URIPATH. But the above method is out of my grip.

Thanks
kriss332

Comment: [Same question on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/85171/539)

Comment: Ya, I asked it there too. Since the number of questions here are too huge. So hoped to ask it somewhere else too.

Comment: And it doesn't appear to be particularly on-topic in either place.  Try reading the source code.

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer, I wasnt looking at the code part. poc was just an argument passed to program.